# Vue object with reactivity. How to turn [{…}, __ob__: Observer] in [{…}]?

Tags: vue.js, v-for

**Usecase:**

Parent component:

```
<form-component :fields="form.fields" />

components: {formComponent},
data () {
  return {
    form: {
      fields: [
        {type: 'phone', name: 'phone'}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In child component in `data` i'm added some properties in `fields` props

**Variant 1:**

```
vm.arr // [{…}, __ob__: Observer]
vm.arr= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(vm.arr))
vm.arr // [{…}, __ob__: Observer]


mounted () {
  let vm = this
  vm.formatFields = vm.fields.map(function (f) {
    f.invalid = false
    return f
  })
  vm.formatFields = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(vm.formatFields))
},
```

But it looks bad :(

Comment: If you do that, you will lose reactivity for `this.arr` in Vue. Is that your intent?

Comment: @Bert updated question

Comment: Are you trying to make a copy of the object in the child?

Comment: @Bert i,m trying to change property of object in props array  in the child through copy of the object